# Is available java annotation overloading?

Tags: java, annotations, overloading

I define an annotation.

```
@Documented
@Target(value = ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ApiParameter {
public String name() default "";

public String type() default "";

public String desc() default "";
}
```

I can use this annotation like above, in method parameter declaratation.

```
...
@ApiParameter(desc="for desc") String userName,
@ApiParameter(name="for name", desc="for desc") String address,
@ApiParameter(name="for name",type="for type",desc="for desc") Order order
...
```

How can I use like above? I want avoid typing field name.

```
...
@ApiParameter("for desc") String userName,
@ApiParameter("for name", "for desc") String address,
@ApiParameter("for name","for type" "for desc") Order order,
...
```

Plz help~

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632659/java-annotation-overloading

Answer (score 1):

Only *Single-Element* annotations [[JLS-9.7.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.3)] are allowed to use

```
@Identifier ( ElementValue )
```

as shorthand for `@Identifier(value = ElementValue)`.

You can use Single element annotations only when your annotation type has a `value` element and all other elements (if any) have default values.

If you absolutely have to avoid using field names in the annotation you could create an annotation with a single `String[] value()` element.

```
public @interface ApiParameter {
    public String[] value();
}
```

And then use it as

```
@ApiParameter({"for name", "for desc"}) String param
```

However, I think this solution would be less clear and more error prone than your current one and you would also have to check that the array had the correct amount of elements when accessing it through the annotation.